# Is it possible to simplify this function in a way that the summation symbol is removed?

Tags: functions, summation, finance

$$
f(t)=\sum_{t_0=0}^{t} ab^{t_0}
$$

In which $a$ and $b$ are constants, and $t$ is variable.

The purpose of the function is to describe the performance of a fixed income investment with monthly contributions. $a$ is the value that is added each month, $b$ is the monthly fee summed with 1, $t$ is the period in months, and $f(t)$ is the value of the investment after $t$ months.

$$
f(t)=kb^t+\sum_{t_0=0}^{t} ab^{t_0}
$$

This is the same function considering there was an ammount already invested when $t=0$, represented by $k$.

These functions are not practical to be calculated without the help of a computer program, so I was wondering if there is a way of removing the summation from them.

Comment: Google geometric series

Comment: I'm assuming you intended the inner term to be $ab^{t_0}$, otherwise you would have result $(t+1)ab^t$...

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly that, somehow forgot the existence of this concept

Comment: The right expression is $ f(t)=kb^t+\sum\limits_{\color{red}x=0}^{t-1} ab^{\color{red}x}$, if you invest at the end of the month.

Comment: I was considering the investment would be made in the beginning of the month, but your expression would be better for most people I guess

Comment: @Antonio In this case it is $f(t)=kb^t+\sum\limits_{\color{red}x=1}^{t} ab^{\color{red}x}$.
I hope you can see the difference.

Comment: As QC_QAOA pointed out, it is some partial geometric series, hence $\displaystyle\sum_{t_0=0}^tab^{t_0} = a\frac{1-b^{t+1}}{1-b}$.

Comment: @callculus42 I understand. The main difference is that in the first equation you presented, you are considering the months in an ordinal way, as first month, second month, etc. $t$ would be the month in which the last investment was made. In the equation from the post, I considered months as a unit of time, so $t$ would be the time passed after the first investment, so $f(0)=a$ would make sense.

Comment: @abiessu thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: @Antonio But then my first formula would make more sense, imho. You make make t payments and not t+1 payments, right? Please check that. It seems that something is not fully understand yet.

Comment: @Abezhiko Yes, I'm going to mark the post as solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonio You're welcome :)

Comment: @callculus42 I agree, your formula is the best suited considering the context of finance, but I woudn't deem the other as wrong, and I personally prefer it.

Comment: @Antonio The problem is, that the results of the formulas are different. As I said, the number of payments (periods) are different. In my case it is $t$, while in the other case it is $t+1$

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, the summation portion of the function can be expressed as the sum of a geometric progression:

$f(t)=kb^t+a(b^{t+1}-1)/(b-1);t≥0; b≠1$